# Change custom field position in checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I'm currently working on a custom shipping method for Magento 1.9.

Right now, I have to add a custom field in the checkout page and fill it with the timeslots available for delivery (I plan to add a select field).

I followed this tutorial : http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2015/08/20/checkout-add-extra-address-field/#disqus_thread to create a custom field and save it in the database when the customer make an order.

It's working but I don't know how to change the field position from billing/shipping address block to shipping method block. I want to place my field after the shipping methods.

I tried to do something like this :

layout file (app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/address.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name='checkout.onepage.shipping_method.available'>
            <block type='checkout/onepage_shipping_method_available' name='form.additional.info' template='checkout/onepage/shipping_method/timeslots_field.phtml'></block>
            <!-- <block type='checkout/onepage_shipping_method' name='form.additional.info' template='address/checkout/onepage/billing_field.phtml'></block> -->
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>
</layout>
```

template file (app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/timeslots_field.phtml) :

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="available:delivery_instruction" class="required">
        <?php echo $this->__('Delivery Instructions') ?>
    </label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" name="available[delivery_instruction]" id="available:delivery_instruction" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getDeliveryInstruction()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Delivery Instructions') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />
    </div>
</div>
```

template file (app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml)

```
// lot of stuff
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
```

Does someone can help me ?

Thanks.

Edit : edited code with newest version, I can't manage to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

Don't change base files;
create copy of

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml
```

To

```
 /app/design/frontend/default/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml
```

Now add line

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
```

At last in phtml.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand well : I create copy of /app/design/frontend/base files I need in /app/design/frontend/default (e.g. my layout and my template) instead of using directly base files. Btw, which template should I use ? available.phtml or my template (timeslots_field.phtml).

Next, I just have to add the `$this->getChildHtml()` line to make it work.
Well... I tried but it doesn't work (the field is not appearing).

Comment: did you try adding <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>  in available.phtml ?

Comment: Yes, I also tried something like this : `Test1 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?> Test2`
I can see Test1 & Test2 but there is nothing between them.

Answer (score 2):

You should add call

```
$this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info')
```

in template of

```
checkout.onepage.shipping_method
```

block in the place where you want to see it